# What does "down" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [*Greyhound (2020)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_%28film%29), Rudel meets Charlie Cole for spoiled ships' radar complaint:

> Charlie Cole: What can we do about this damn interference?
>
> Rudel: It's not interference, sir. I checked everything. The pilot
> light's on, no surge currents, and I reset the overload relay four
> days ago. I could reset it again, but we're gonna be **down** nearly two
> hours. Waste of time, sir.

What does "down" mean here?

Comment: Wiktionary [down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down#Adjective) sense 8

Comment: I think the cited usage is effectively an anachronism. This use of ***down*** for ***out of operation or unavailable for use*** barely existed until well after WW2, and it certainly never *started* as "naval jargon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the radar or sonar will be, off, offline, inoperative, not working, broken, etc. A piece of equipment may be “down” intentionally (for repair, maintenance, or regular schedule), or unintentionally (due to loss of power, improperly working, or inoperative).